# MongoLab: Does hardware effect performance of a find() query

Tags: performance, mongodb, nosql, hardware

I asked a pervious question on StackOverflow about if document size affected the performance of fetching that document (the document is 3MB in size) 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30226219/does-the-size-of-a-document-affect-performance-of-a-find-query

The conclusion was, yes it does. It seems that the larger the document you are trying to fetch (using the find() query) the longer it will take to get a response (because the document will take longer to download given it's larger size)

Currently I'm hosting my database on MongoLab. I'm currently using the free sandbox tier, but I do plan on upgrading to a shared or dedicated plan in a few months.

My question is, will upgrading to a shared or dedicated plan improve the performance of downloading a large document? I'm assuming it will because the paid plans have better hardware, but will the performance improvements be noticeable/significant. Just curious what other thought.

Comment: Available server resources can definitely affect the speed of results. Unless there is an issue with provisioning it seems likely that a dedicated plan should overall be better than a shared plan, and either of those should be an improvement on a free plan. However, the actual outcome will depend on your use case and where your performance bottleneck(s) are. You're best asking MongoLab directly to find out what relative performance benefits to expect.

Answer (score 1):

All things being equal, it is logical to assume that better hardware = better performance. However, computers are strange beasts - I know that with Oracle, if you assign very large sizes (you need good hardware) to certain caches, you can actually slow down the machine.

The only real suggestion that I have is that you test, test and test again. [You cannot manage what you cannot measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._Edwards_Deming).